# Angular 4, ng new doesn't create node_modules in project directory?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, angular-cli

Just re-installed Angular and started a new project using ng new, but I couldn't execute ng serve after I made the new project and cd into it. In my Mac Mini after I ng new a new project, I can just cd into the project folder and do ng serve, in my Windows 10 I need to execute npm install first cause straight ng serve gave me error.

[image]

After I checked the project folder, its because ng new doesn't make a node_moodules in the new project and download all the required packages ( ng new executed very fast ).

Based on the documentation and most setup guides out there, after ng new we can go straightly to ng serve after change the directory to the project directory. Is there something wrong with my installation ( Node, angular, npm, etc... ) or this is normal ?

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I use Angular CLI 1.2.1 in the Windows 10 and Angular CLI 1.2.0 in OSX.

Comment: Just re-installed it again on Mac and it gives error (although the error is different) now if I don't do npm install, so I guess in the new Angular CLI version, we need to do npm install first, hope this helps you and the documentation should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing Angular 2 and having the same issues
Everyone out there is trying to solve the issue by suggesting solutions that worked with previous versions or maybe AngularJS

Its true you have to do npm install every time you create a new project because that creates the node_modules folder