# Installed npm globally, still for each Angular Project It is giving me ERROR to install it again

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have recently started learning Angular 4. So as mentioned in a tutorial I have installed nodejs, then angular 4 cli and create a project to start working. I did the same and looks perfect but when I use `ng serve --open` to run local server. It gives me following error:

[image: Angular ng serve --o ERROR]

I have solved this issue with installing npm again in my angular app directory.

Now I am going to create a new app which is giving the same error and I don't want to install npm again and again for each project (the issue is also solved by copying `node_modules` folder from first app root to the new app) because I am in a learning phase so I am required to create a new project for each new thing I learn.

**Update:**
I am using Windows 8.1, latest version of Nodejs v8.1.4 (also tried the LTS), npm version 5.0.3 and Visual Studio Code. Everything installs perfectly without any error.

Comment: Did you install https://github.com/angular/angular-cli ?

Comment: Yup I have Installed Angular-cli using  npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Check your `package.json` and see what is there for `ng serve --open`

Comment: Everything works fine if I use npm install in the app root dir or copy and paste npm_module folder from existing app into the new app dir.

Comment: {
  "name": "quiz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },

Comment: my package.json has only one instance of ng serve. It is "start": "ng serve"

Comment: If I use ng start it says this is an invalid command

Comment: it should be npm start, not ng start.

Comment: npm start doesn't work as well :(

Comment: it wont, until you do npm install as it needs the various modules for compiling. Unless node_modules folder is not there the compilation cant happen.

Comment: @VishalGulati But this thing is not mentioned in my video tutorial series. Tutor's app automatically created npm_modules folder. Even official angular documentation doesn't say anything like this. It is supposed to create module folder by default.

Comment: yes, i am amazed too why it did not create. Give me 30-40 minutes. Will try the same procedure with latest version of cli.

Comment: Thanks I am waiting for any helpful answer :)

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using? Are you running all of your commands as an admin/root user? Are you getting any errors during any package install process? **Please, add this information to the question, not in the comments**.

Comment: @R.Richards Done. Thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: I would really like to see the exact version numbers for node and npm. The latest can mean a couple of things whether you have the LTS (6.11.x), or Current (8.1.x). The LTS works well, every time. Current (8.1.x) may seem to work, but is problematic. Be very specific.

Comment: @R.Richards Is it ok now?

Comment: Good, thanks. I suggest you uninstall nodejs 8.1, install version 6.11.1, then try it all again (uninstall/reinstall the angular CLI, create a new project using the CLI, run ng serve).  Run your npm commands using an administrative command prompt. You should have a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Any new project created with `@angular/cli` doesn't ship node_modules out of the box. You got to run `npm install` in every single proejct you create. (This is not the case with React CLI "`create-react-app`".) The package json file is generated with every new project created. So just run `npm install` in the root folder.

Dont copy the node_modules folder of any existing project. It may have dev/production dependencies that you may not need in your new project so why keep junk.

The minimal package json created by CLI in your app folder has following scripts in place:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

So if you do `npm start` or `ng serve` both will do the same.

Comment: when you create a new project using ng new <project-name>, doest it have node_modules folder in plcae in root directory?

Comment: No it doesn't create node_module folder by default. If I copy and paste that folder from any existing project everything works fine.

Comment: ok, it must have created package.json there? Found similar issue reported today. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156751/angular-4-ng-new-doesnt-create-node-modules-in-project-directory

Comment: Yeah, package.json is created in the app root dir.